# How to add a hyperlink to Excel cell using TMS Flexcel

Tags: tms

I am creating an Excel file using TMS Flexcel. I have a master worksheet that list all of the worksheets in the workbook. On the master worksheet I want to add in text with a link to all of the other worksheets.

I have the following code creating a hyperlink and adding it to the excel file.

```
var hyperLink = new THyperLink(THyperLinkType.CurrentWorkbook, inputFile.FileCode, "Link to another worksheet", inputFile.FileCode + "#A1", null);
```

So once I have added the hyperlink I can't figure out how to add it to a cell in the master worksheet. I tried the following but it won't work:

```
excelFile.SetCellValue(1, 2, hyperLink, 4);
```

What the above outputs in cell B2 is: "FlexCel.Core.THyperLink"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question. I forgot to go back and answer my question once I found a solution.

```
            var link = new THyperLink(THyperLinkType.CurrentWorkbook, "", "Master List", "", "'Master List'!D" + (sheetIndex + 1));
            excelFile.AddHyperLink(new TXlsCellRange(1, 1, 1, 1), link);
```

You have to use the AddHyperLink method to add a hyperlink to a cell.